# Alcatel Onetouch Pop 3 5.5 bootloop

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, boot-loop

I've recently tried to root my device with [this tutorial](http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/general/how-to-root-alcatel-pop-3-5-5-5025d-t3424467). But now when I start my phone it restarts after 5 seconds and then it shows the teamwin logo. After that it says:

```
Could not mount /data and unable to find crypto footer.
Failed to mount '/data' (Invalid argument)
Unable to recreate /data/media folder.
Updating partition details...
Failed to mount '/data' (Invalid argument)
...done
Unable to mount storage
Failed to mount '/data' (Invalid argument)
Full SELinux support is present.
Unable to mount /data/media/TWRP/.twrps
Running Recovery Commands
Failed to mount '/data' (Invalid argument)
Formatting Cache using make_ext4fs...
Failed to mount '/data' (Invalid argument)
Done processing script file
Renamed stock recovery file in /system to prevent
the stock ROM from replacing TWRP.
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this? I'm at the point that I don't care about the root anymore I just want my phone to act normal again.

Just to make sure everybody understands: my phone can't load recovery nor load fastboot mode.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to say, you may have bricked your phone...
pardon me for any mistakes, I am only 14 years old

try reinstalling the kernel and bootloader (I suggest using clockworkmod for bootloader) through Odin - Google how to do it if you don't know

then delete cache, dalvik cache and finally factory reset your phone - all through bootloader like ClockWorkMod

Download a ROM like Cyanogenmod
Download GAPPS for the ROM
Put all of this on SD card

Flash the Rom and GAPPS through bootloader

And finally reboot your phone - If you get a message from the bootloader asking if you would like to fix root, simply select yes

You can activate root by going on to developer options on CyanogenMod

Comment: Thanks for replying! For sofar I've read my phone is not "bricked", it is stuck in bootloop. Do you have a tutorial for me how to use Odin on a phone that is stuck in bootloop? Or mabey another program or method to fix this?

Comment: Umm... Give me like 10 mins, I will find a tutorial for u...

Comment: This is a tutorial that shows how to recover from boot loop: http://xda-university.com/as-a-user/how-to-recover-from-a-bootloop

Comment: This one shows how to use Odin on Samsung... http://androidflagship.com/791-update-root-android-samsung-device-odin You can use this tutorial for your phone... Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

I've found a way to undo this.
Alcatel does offer repair tools on their [site](http://www.alcatel-mobile.com/global-en/support/softwareUpgrade/list). Simply select Pop 3 (5.5) from the list on the left and download the tool. Just follow the steps exactly and your device will boot properly.

If I find a way to root this device I will post it here as well.